# Magento1.9 : array_key_exists deprecated in after upgrade php7.4

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, php-7.4

Am upgrading my magento1.9 site to php version 7.4. I got array_key_exists is deprecated in 7.4 version. In my magento site how to change that function. Some one says use isset or property_exists. How to use this and which one is better.

Comment: By default Magento1.9 supports up to Php7.2x versions. If you are trying to use Php7.4 it will require more efforts

Comment: @Mukesh all efforts i did only pending with array_key_exists function.How to do in this better way